# Upcoming Date Function

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 different dates and I'm trying to code what the closest upcoming date is. If the date is in the past it needs to be ignored. Also, date1 <= date2 <= date3

I've tried the following code with (8/18/2021, 8/19/2021, 8/20/2021) as an inputs, but the function returns 12:00:00AM not 8/18/2021

```
Public Function UpcomingDates(date1 As Date, date2 As Date, date3 As Date) As Date

Dim ClosestDate As Date

If date1 >= Date Then   'diff1 >= 0
    ClosestDate = date1
ElseIf date2 >= Date Then
    ClosestDate = date2
ElseIf date2 >= Date Then
    ClosestDate = date3
End If

End Function
```

Why doesn't the function return 8/18/2021?

*I'm using VBA in MS Access Query

Comment: You have not set the function to return a value, just declared the datatype that it will return - try adding `UpcomingDates=ClosestDate` just before `End Function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are stored in Access (and other office products) as serial numbers. For example, "1/1/2008" is actually stored as 39448. The number 39448 is the number of days since Jan 1, 1900. Decimals of this number represent the time of day. So a data value with no decimal is assumed to be 12:00:00 AM. For example, 39448.25 would be 1/1/2008 6am, 39448.5 would be 1/1/2008 12pm, etc.

To have a function display the date only, use the format function:

```
Format(ClosestDate, "m/d/yyyy")
```

Comment: Hi just one more question about this. If all three dates have passed how do I get the function to return nothing so that the Access field in datasheet view is blank?